# How can I access and update st.line_chart in other .py file in streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

My project is to make a live graph according to an updating log file generated from the `simpy` module, but I don't know how to make the `st.line_chart` -> `inf_chart` to be a variable so that I can use `add_rows` to update the chart.

In mainpage.py

```
if st.button('Run simulator'):
 ...
 infrastructure, application = st.columns(2)
 empty = ['']
 empty_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(empty,columns=[''])
 ...
 inf_chart = infrastructure.line_chart(empty_dataframe,width=500)
 app_chart = application.line_chart(empty_dataframe,width=500)
```

In UI.py

```
import mainpage
def draw_infrastructure(element,i,columns):
    df = pd.DataFrame(element,index=[i],columns=[columns])
    inf_chart.add_rows(df)
```

`draw_infrastructure` runs every time when the log file updates, but it becomes two same pages when I import `mainpage` in UI.py. Is there any solution to pass this variable `inf_chart`  to another file?

Comment: So you want to create a live chart and the live data is from `draw_infrastructure()`?